# OpenEdge SQL ODBC shows different column size than native ABL does

Tags: sql, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I'm using the Progress OpenEdge ODBC driver (peoe27.dll v07.16.0175) to push data into an OpenEdge database. I had a situation where a user put in a string value that was 54 characters long, which got rejected during the update because it exceeded the defined column size of 50, as visible in the second image below.

The legacy system admin then sent me a screen shot showing that, as far as ABL was concerned, the width on that same column in that same table was 200 characters. (see the first image)

Anyone have an explanation? (Other than that ABL and OpenEdge ODBC are a terrible platform... :P )

[image: Progress ABL version]
[image: OpenEdge ODBC version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legacy DB admin found the answer. Seems there are ways to change the schema of an OpenEdge table that does not get "published" in such a way that external requesters can see it.

Apparently there is a "dbtool utility in dlc" that can scan and fix this. He researched it and did just that.

If you're reading this with similar issues and the above isn't enough to get you  past, PM and I'll get more details.

Comment: The dbtool utility scans the rows and adjusts a field called "sqlwidth". The format "x(200)" is just a hint for default screen layouts. It is not an actual field width or column size in the SQL sense.